# Skin fallback mechanism

Tags: theme, parent-child-theme, skin, theme-fallback

having some products with a customised design using a child product view template, can I use the skin folder of the parent one?
Here is my scenario in System->configuration->design:

Current Package Name > Default

Default > customised_theme

Here is the scenario in Product > Design
Custom Design > customised_theme_child (i've just duplicated the directory structure and copied the file template/catalog/product/view.phtml)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you set up the fallback
Let's say you have this scenario

- base

  - default
- your custom theme

  - default `< holds the default layout of your shop`
  - product one template `< holds product specific layout`
  - product two template `< holds product specific layout`

Under `System > Config > Design > Package` your *Current Package Name* should be the name of your custom theme.

With above settings it should fall back in the right way for you to use the parents *skin* directory

Comment: I added my current scenario, can u help me more? thanks

Comment: Hi Antonio, with your current set up I don't think it will work. Therefor I would advise you to use above setup described in my answer

Comment: I think I can't specify the custom theme as current package, because it was developed as variation of the default template. What about if I copy the skin/custom_theme folder under skin/default?

Comment: It would work if you use the `default/default` directory for your skin. Magento falls back to that